# Moving asp site to new windows server, ADOBD connection error

Tags: asp-classic, ado

Hi I have been tasked with moving an asp application to a new server, however I receive the following error:

ADODB.Connection error '800a0e78'

Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

I am not sure what i'm missing as I don't have much experience with asp. I have registered a dll file with windows moved the DB accross and scoured every forum I can find to look for similar issues, however they all say that there is a coding issue. The site has been running smoothly for 18 months on another server so I don't see how there could be any problem with the code.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause if it was working previously, is that your connection isn't set up correctly. Perhaps the database is in a different location, perhaps it's using different credentials, perhaps a provider is missing, perhaps an ODBC connection is missing.

The reason you are seeing "operation is not allowed when the object is closed" is likely because there is some "on error resume" type code where your db connection code exists, which is transparently swallowing the connection errors. So the code continues thinking that the connection is open.

Comment: thanks for your response, I have only found 1 on error resume next in the script I removed it but no change.   This is the code that is producing the error Function LoginStatus()
    Set clsSQL = Server.CreateObject("xxxxxxx.SQL")
        clsSQL.LanguageSelector(Request.QueryString("lang"))
        If clsSQL.AccessChecker() = False Then
            bLogin = False
        Else
            bLogin = True
        End if
    Set clsSQL = Nothing
    LoginStatus = bLogin
End Function

Comment: How does the application connect to the database? ODBC? Access? SQL Server? If ODBC, have you created the DSN used by the existing server? Can you connect to the same datasource using another application?

Comment: It is using SQL server, but I can't seem to find the settings for connecting to SQL, as I'm not an asp programmer I am not entirely sure where it would be especially as the site is huge.  It can't be using ODBC as there are no ODBC connections setup on the original server.  I don't know how I would go about testing the datasource, as I have never used MSSQL only mysql

Comment: Okay great, is it the same sql server as the previous website was using or a new install?

Comment: It is a new install on the new server

Comment: I have used ms deploy to move the database

Comment: Ok, did you add the login used for the database (assuming you are using username/pass sql authentication) to base sql server as well as the database? Having the permissions on the database isn't enough, you need to add the login to the server too.

Is the SQL connection a local connection? Is the instance name the same as the old server?

Comment: you may just have something there, I have added the user but I have just realised that I cannot reveal the original password, how could I find out the password that the script is using for sql connection? The connection is local. I'm not sure what the instance name is

Comment: do a search for the user in the code, or look for a code file that contains the connection information, ultimately from here its going to be a debugging exercise which is probably outside the scope of being useful on a Q&A site, good luck!

Comment: i've discovered the connection string and updated all the settings however the error is exactly the same, maybe I have not set sql up properly, I have just tested a connection from a new script  and it still doesn't work maybe it is an issue with the connection string:      Application("CONN_STRING") = "Driver={SQL Native Client};Server="&Application("DB_SERVER")&";Database="&Application("DB_NAME")&";Uid="&Application("DB_UID")&";Pwd="&Application("DB_PWD")&";"